# Is it possible to "install" a hook that will be called before removal of a package?

Tags: apt

Background: on Ubuntu I like to prevent `sshd` from logging errors when trying to load the `ssh_host_dsa_key` file when I remove it. There appears to be no configuration option in `sshd_config` to prevent `sshd` from attempting this. Hence I use `chattr +i` to set the immutable attribute on the file, after emptying it out.

Now, let's take this particular example (`openssh-server` package) in your answer.

**Question:** How can I install a script that runs prior to anything the package itself may call during removal (purge)?

As you can imagine, when purging (`apt-get --purge remove`) the package, it fails due to the immutable attribute. Such a hook would allow me to remove the immutable attribute and allow the package removal to succeed.

---

If the DSA key cannot be loaded the following error appears in the logs:

```
sshd[5669]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform arbitrary uninstall actions via the `prerm` and `postrm` scripts in the deb package, you could rebuild the package for this, but it *may* also work if you edit the `openssh-server.prerm` (in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`). (These are similar to the RPM spec file `%preun` and `%postun` sections.)

The current OpenSSH package uses these to `update-alternatives`, and do the config file clean up. You can see these for example [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/openssh-server) in the `openssh_6.6p1-2ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz` package setup that Ubuntu use.

See https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html
(section 7.6 especially).

My understanding of the installation and operation of the OpenSSH package on Ubuntu is that the various keys are only created on new install, rather than on demand at each startup as with some distributions.

I believe the only other type of "hook" Ubuntu offers are the crash-detection [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport/DeveloperHowTo), which isn't useful here.

`sshd` itself does not create the file you reference, but (`sshd_config` default `HostKey` settings) will expect it to exist. At this time OpenSSH does not let you choose which hostkey algorithms to enable *explicitly*, as with say `KexAlgorithms`, they are enabled *implicitly* when viable host keys of each type (RSA, DSS, ECDSA) are found at startup. The alternative is to specify a `HostKey` for each type of key you wish to support to override the default.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the information I was looking for. Now I need to verify that I can modify these scripts freely without breaking the removal process. Unfortunately using `HostKey` doesn't work, as it only provides a way to override the default, not to disable it as far as I could tell from the debug output when running `$(which sshd) -Dddddp 22`.

Comment: `HostKey` affects `sshd` at runtime, but it also has some effect at install time, see the `openssh-server.postinst` script. The default new `sshd_config` there is the root of this behaviour, the installer is smart enough to only generate the keys indicated in an existing or new config though.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Note that the `prerm` script will be overwritten each time you upgrade the package.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a hook for the `dpkg` command. Create a file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/my_hook` (create the directory if it doesn't exist) containing

```
pre-invoke=/usr/local/sbin/dpkg-pre-hook
```

The program `/usr/local/sbin/dpkg-pre-hook` is executed before `dpkg` performs an operation. The environment variable `DPKG_HOOK_ACTION` contains the action that `dpkg` is performing: one of `install`, `unpack`, `configure`, `remove` or `purge` any maybe a few more. You don't get to know the names of the packages that are being manipulated — these hooks were designed to update the system state (e.g. to keep an index of packages or documentation up-to-date), not to influence the behavior of individual packages. Nonetheless, you can tell what is going on by looking at the arguments passed to `dpkg`. This isn't fully robust but should work as long as the system administrator doesn't try to break it.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\t' read -a arguments < <(</proc/$PPID/cmdline tr '\0' '\t')
shift arguments
case $DPKG_HOOK_ACTION in
  remove|purge)
    for x in "${arguments[@]}"; do
      case $x in
        openssh-server) …;;
      esac
    done
esac
```

---

Your example is very strange. You're [almost certainly barking up the wrong tree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The Ubuntu package does not create a new `ssh_host_ecdsa_key` file when you remove the package (what a bizarre thing to do!). It *removes* that key file (along with other key files and other configuration files) when you *purge* the package. If you don't wish for the key file to be removed, either remove the package instead of purging it, or make a backup of the key file.

If you don't want the SSH server to use a particular key type (which is probably not a good idea in the first place), don't fiddle with file attributes. Use the option to that effect in the configuration file: pass the `HostKey` option explicitly for the keys that you want to use, and the default key file names will not be used.

For files that are provided by a package (which is not the case for SSH key files, which have to be generated on each machine), use [`dpkg-divert`](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/118/Replacing_binaries_with_dpkg-divert) if you don't want a particular file to be at its package-provided location.